# Extending User Model Twice?

Tags: python, django

NOTE - I am not sure if this type of question is allowed and I apologize if not.

Hello,
So up until now I have been using Django-Allauth for the registration on my site however I find it to be very limiting and thus I have decided to develop my own registration system for the website. At this stage I want to have two different registration forms, my question/concern is how I should best approach extending the user model. Should I have two models both with a one to one field, or should I have two models which don't connect with the user model and just put two forms in the registration view (one for the user mnodel and for the custom fields) or perhaps an entirely different method all together. Below is the code I have been playing around with but some advice on what I should do would be much appreciated! Cheers

Models -

```
class StudentForm(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class EmployerForm(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tester = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Admin -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import StudentForm, EmployerForm

class StudentFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__"]

    class Meta:
        model = StudentForm

class EmployerFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "tester"]

    class Meta:
        model = StudentForm


admin.site.register(StudentForm, StudentFormAdmin)
admin.site.register(EmployerForm, EmployerFormAdmin)
```

Error -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/registration/studentform/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'main',
 'listings',
 'profiles',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'registration')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1468.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in __init__
  79.         self.get_results(request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in get_results
  174.         result_count = paginator.count

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in count
  371.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_count
  483.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_aggregation
  464.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/registration/studentform/
Exception Value: no such table: registration_studentform
```

Comment: This looks good except that `model = StudentForm` should be `model = EmployerForm` for `EmployerFormAdmin`. Are you facing any issue in particular ?

Comment: I was more just wanting to know if this was a good way to do it. I am however having an error where if I try and access the models in the admin panel I get an error (added it to the question). Also this is persisting after I made the change you told me.

Comment: You havent created and/or run the migrations most likely. Hence the error

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest more straightforward and [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) way of extending user model:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

USER_ROLE_STUDENT = 1
USER_ROLE_EMPLOYER = 2

USER_ROLES = (
        (USER_ROLE_STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (USER_ROLE_EMPLOYER, 'Employer'),
    )


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    role = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=USER_ROLES, default=USER_ROLE_STUDENT)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=10)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    if created:
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

And about your error... I guess it's because you haven't run migration indeed.